# How to turn checkbox with IF formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I have a cell with an "end date" and I have a checkbox under an "Inactive" labelled column. I would like that checkbox to turn on when today's date is after the end date.

I can't seem to add a formula of the checkbox cell without breaking it. So I have tried to a formula in the cell beside it saying:

```
=IF (E5 < TODAY(), G5=1, G5=2)
```

where E5 is the "end date" cell and G5 is the checkbox.

It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(E5 < TODAY(), 0, 1)
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zq386jTZ65KYi0SoxA9r_jUFKH9g5srwFhblLJptS1c/edit#gid=0)**